# Mail php script

Tags: php, email

I have the following mail php script, and would like to add 2 new variables "company" and "name"

what would be the best way to add these 2 variable so that they appear in the body of the sent email?

Thanks
JB

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

mail( "x.com", "Feedback Form Results",
$message, "From: $email" );
header( "Location: http://www.xxx.com/thankyou.html" );
?>
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to header injection. Ensure that `$email` doesn't contain any linebreaks!

Comment: Every time I read a question like this I always picture some guy firing his php developer because "he was just getting all his answers from SO, I can do that."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it so really hard to just concatenate a couple variables?

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] . $_REQUEST['var1'] . $_REQUEST['var2'];
```

This isn't rocket science. It's barebones bedrock PHP.